# How to call a large list of paired files to be executed by a program in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, dna-sequence

I have a large directory of files (100+) that I'd like to pass through a program via the terminal.

The files are paired and all follow a naming scheme like such:

```
 TS-8_S53_L001_R1_001.fastq 
 TS-8_S53_L001_R2_001.fastq
 RS-9_S54_L001_R1_001.fastq 
 RS-9_S54_L001_R2_001.fastq
```

And the program execution looks like:

```
Seqprogram -i1 Blah_R1_001.fastq -i2 Blah_R2_001.fastq -o Blah_paired.fastq
```

All of these files are in one directory.

I'd like to able to run the program on all of the files, using the files paired together in the proper sequence (R1 files are passed through i1, the R1 and R2 files have the same base name) and the output file (-o) is saved under the base name with some identifier attached ("_paired", etc).

I've envisioned on how I'd do this over Python; however, I am trying to get better with BASH.

I'm familiar with how one might call multiple files into a single command; i.e., uncompressing all .gz files in a particular directory

```
gunzip "*.gz"
```

But this command has two inputs, and the inputs must be ordered, so the wildcard scheme isn't sufficient.

Thanks

Comment: It'd help if you showed not just the first execution, but the second one as well.

Comment: Do you mean @Charles, `Seqprogram -i1 TS-8_S53_L001_R1_001.fastq -i2 TS-8_S53_L001_R2_001.fastq -o TS-8_S53_L001.fastq `

`Seqprogram -i1 RS-9_S54_L001_R1_001.fastq 
 -i2 RS-9_S54_L001_R2_001.fastq -o  RS-9_S54.fastq `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard to get one file of the pair, and then use parameter substitution to get the other corresponding filenames.

```
for i1 in *_R1_001.fastq; do
    i2=${i1/R1_001/R2_001}
    paired=${i1/R1_001/paired}
    Seqprogram -i1 "$i1" -i2 "$i2" -o "$paired"
done
```

Comment: Hmm. I was a few tens of seconds ahead of you on first-to-post, but you were obviously working on improving this question before I got here; trying to decide whether to delete my own answer.

Comment: There are some slight differences between our substitutions, it's not clear which one is more appropriate for his needs.

Comment: Fair 'nuff; might as well keep both then.

Comment: I am at a crossroads here. Both of your loops obtain the same result (via echo) and are good examples of how a technique may be modified to reach the same goal (I learned from them anyhow).

Comment: The difference depends on the details of the filename patterns. My answer assumes the filenames all end in `001`, Charles's just looks for `_R1_` and `_R2_`. So how general does it need to be?

Comment: The assumption that all the filenames end in `001` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to match a single one of the three filenames patterned, and to modify it to get the other two.

That is to say:

```
for r1file in *_R1_*.fastq; do
  r2file=${r1file/_R1_/_R2_}
  pairfile=${r1file%_R1_*}_paired.fastq
  Seqprogram -i1 "$r1file" -i2 "$r2file" -o "$pairfile"
done
```